# Could not load file or assembly error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sqlclient

When I'm trying to launch this program:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        string connectionString = null;
        SqlConnection db;
        connectionString = @"Server=DESKTOP-VJ1JVU4\SQLEXPRESS; Database=MainPjDataBase; Connect Timeout=5; User id=admin;Pwd=41234;";
        db = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT oNTO MainTable (id, name, last) VALUES(4, 'nik', 'hin')", db);


        db.Open();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        db.Close();
    }
```

there is an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Thread,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Did you include System.Threading?

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. `INSERT oNTO` should be `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that this code is not causing that error. Your project must have a bad reference or other corruption. I would try this: (1) I don't think this code needs System.Threading.Thread, so delete it from your references. Does it work now? or my last resort routine (2) start a new windows app from File -> new project and gradually add your code to it, checking if it still runs after each small step... Anyway, I'm affraid we haven't got enough info to help you out on this

Comment: Before you do (2), you may also try (1b) open the referencelist of each of your projects. Do you see warning signs next to some references? That may be because of a .NET framework incompatibility between projects. All your projects should target the same .NET framework to prevent such issues: check each of your project's target framework: see Project > Properties > Application tab > Target framework) Else, (2) always works out :)